# Large XML file - wrap elements inside tags using XSLT or by manipulating the XML as String?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I have a fairly large XML file, around 3-4 MB and I need to wrap certain elements inside tags. My Xml has the following structure:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <p>
        <sectPr></sectPr>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <tbl></tbl>
    <p>
        <sectPr></sectPr>
    </p>
</body>
```

Of course, all the `p` and `tbl` elements will repeat themselves inside the `body` until the end of the file (also each of the elements presented above will have children - I just took them out for the sake of simplicity). As an estimate, I will have around 70 elements containing `sectPr` inside `body`, not necessarily in the order I described above.

What I would like to do, is to wrap all the elements that are starting from an element containing `sectPr` to the next element containing `sectPr` into another tag. As a result, my XML should look like this:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <myTag>
        <p>
            <sectPr></sectPr>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <tbl></tbl>
    </myTag>
    <myTag>
        <p>
            <sectPr></sectPr>
        </p>
    </myTag> 
</body>
```

Also, another requirement is that the operation must be performed under 40 seconds.

My question is: Do you think is possible to achieve this result using XSLT and if this is the case could please provide a short description on how can I do it, or do you think is better to read the XML file as String and then add the tags by manipulating the string?

Also, as programming language, I am using Visual Basic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? Can there be a more descendant `sectPr` elements inside `sectPr`? If so would you like to put another tag on them too?

Comment: should add visual basic tag

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0 and only <code>p</code> elements can have either none or at most one <code>sectPr</code> inside them. Also, <code>sectPr</code> doesn't have any children.

Comment: 3-4Mb is not large by today's standards. When I see the phrase "large XML file", I think it must be over 1Gb. And I see no reason why this XSLT transformation should take more than 4 seconds, let alone 40.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am pretty new to XSLT (just started learning 2 weeks ago) and I am not fully accustomed with it yet. Also, at this point in time I'm just a junior programmer so I don't have so much experience in the field. But thank you for the information, I will keep it in mind :).

Comment: @MichaelKay Didn't you teach us that different processors optimize (or not) differently? Applied to a test file of merely 72 KB (app. 5k lines), the transformation took 19 seconds using the XSLT provided by Lingamurthy CS and 5 seconds using mine. This was using the libxslt processor. OTOH, results were instant in both cases when using Saxon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> another requirement is that the operation must be performed under 40
>   seconds.

Performance depends to a very large extent on the specific processor in use. If you are using MSXML, you may benefit significantly by using a so-called "sibling recursion" in this scenario - [as shown recently by Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726229/3016153).

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- start a "chain" for each leading node  -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | *[sectPr]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body/*[sectPr]" priority="1">
    <myTag>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- call the next sibling in chain  -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(sectPr)]"/>
    </myTag>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- call the next sibling in chain  -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][not(sectPr)]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but may I ask you how it works exactly? I would like to understand it better.

Comment: Uhm, I thought the comments were explanatory enough. The general idea is to apply templates (from the context of `body`) only to nodes that have a `sectPr` child. Each of these opens up a `myTag`, copies itself into it, and invites the immediately following sibling to enter - provided it does not have a `sectPr` child of its own.

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet would do. Though the efficiency is more when keys are used, I'm not sure how much time it would take for your file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- key to select following-sibling of current element containing sectPr, and preceding-sibling of the next element containing sectPr -->
    <xsl:key name="following-sectPr" match="*[not(self::*[sectPr])]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[sectPr][1])"/>

    <!-- Identity transform template to copy nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to match the elements containing sectPr and add myTag to them and the elements matching the above declared key -->
    <xsl:template match="*[sectPr]">
        <myTag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current() | key('following-sectPr', generate-id())" mode="copy"/>
        </myTag>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to do nothing for the elements with no sectPr but having a preceding-sibling elment containing sectPr -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(sectPr) and preceding-sibling::*[sectPr]]"/>

    <!-- template to copy elements pushed by the template matching *[sectPr] -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```